# Can we install applications on Mac when the updates are going on in background?

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

Can we install applications on Mac when the updates are going on in background ?

Lets assume that mac update is running and in the meantime, can we do brew install, or install an downloaded application. I am totally aware that we can do other operations like coping files to or from a dir to another as macos is *nix like OS that truely multitasking.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean. Use as many sentences as you need. … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: hope the explanation suffice.